# Serving static files with nodejs and/or hapijs - routing

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

all ! actually I've this in my code...

```
server.register(require('inert'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: 'server_angular2'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

That's works, but my static files are Angular 2 files, so in mostly scenarios it's necessary to configure the routes of the host web server. An example using browserSync:

```
browserSync.init({
   server: {
        baseDir: "./",
        routes: {
            "/home": "index.html",
            "/rooms": "index.html",
            "/favorities": "index.html",
            "/bookings": "index.html",
            "/results": "index.html"
        }
    }
});
```

**The question: How can I implement it using Inert or any other alternative to Inert ?**

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...I found the solution and it's pretty easy..

Just need to add the routes, like...

```
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/home',
        handler: {
            file: 'server_angular2/index.html'
        }
    });
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/rooms',
        handler: {
            file: 'server_angular2/index.html'
        }
    });
```